# Error: cannot create group: User not authorized - unless I login to the workspace UI

Tags: azure-databricks, terraform-provider-databricks

I'm creating a workspace with terraform.  After the workspace resource has finished I'm then trying to create a `databricks_group` with this:

```
resource "databricks_group" "this" {
  for_each = data.azuread_group.this
  display_name = each.key
  external_id = data.azuread_group.this[each.key].object_id
  workspace_access = var.groups[each.key].workspace_access
  databricks_sql_access = var.groups[each.key].databricks_sql_access
  allow_cluster_create = var.groups[each.key].allow_cluster_create
  allow_instance_pool_create = var.groups[each.key].allow_instance_pool_create
  force = true
}
```

This fails with:

```
╷
│ Error: cannot create group: User not authorized. Using azure-cli auth: host=https://adb-5341709998635988.8.azuredatabricks.net
│ 
│   with databricks_group.this["dbadmins"],
│   on stuff.tf line 23, in resource "databricks_group" "this":
│   23: resource "databricks_group" "this" {
│
```

I then login to the workspace from the Azure portal until I see this screen:

[image]

At this point I can re-run terraform and the `databricks_group` gets created with no error:

```
Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.
databricks_group.this["dbadmins"]: Creating...
databricks_group.this["dbadmins"]: Creation complete after 2s [id=1069087906420767]

Apply complete! Resources: 1 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.
```

I'm using

```
databricks = {
  source = "databricks/databricks"
  version = "1.3.0"
}
```

The workspace and the databricks group are created in different terraform projects using terragrunt.  The terragrunt config for the databricks group project has a dependency on the workspace project:

```
dependency "workspace" {
  config_path = "../workspace"
}

inputs = {
  databricks_resource_id = dependency.workspace.outputs.resource_id
}
```

Any idea why this is failing unless I login?

Comment: Is workspace also created by you, or it was created by service principal?

Comment: The workspace is created by me

Answer (score 1):

I was missing a `azure_workspace_resource_id` in my provider definition:

```
provider "databricks" {
  host = local.databricks_workspace_host
  auth_type  = "azure-cli"
}
```

Adding this (as below) resolved the issue for me:

```
provider "databricks" {
  azure_workspace_resource_id = data.azurerm_databricks_workspace.this.id
  host = local.databricks_workspace_host
  auth_type  = "azure-cli"
}
```